# How to monitor file renaming and removal with only "stat" permission?

Tags: android, linux, posix, stat

There's a file, which my program has no read nor write permission, but only stat permission, as its parent directory has "x" permission (drwxrwxr-x).

I want to monitor the rename and removal of that file. Currently a timer task with stat() call is used in my program for that purpose. It's obviously inefficient for time-sensitive monitoring.

Is there any real-time monitor mechanism for file renaming and removal with only stat permission?

PS, my program runs on Android, but any solution for general Linux is welcome.

Comment: Using `inotify` to be notified about FS events?

Comment: inotify refuses to work due to lack of read permission.